# Windows form receive text input

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Hey guys/girls I got myself stuck and I was hoping I could get some help with it. simply said I'm trying to make a soccerpool on windows form. Because the player can put in as many team's as he/she wants I put the code that makes the betting panels in a (for)loop with the text as 0. very handy if I say so myself but now I can't retrieve the correct input from the user or without breaking the loop. any idea's?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < hometable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRowHome = hometable.Rows[i];
            DataRow dataRowAway = awayTable.Rows[i];
            
            Label lblHomeTeam = new Label();
            Label lblAwayTeam = new Label();
            
            TextBox txtHomePred = new TextBox();
            TextBox txtAwayPred = new TextBox();

            lblHomeTeam.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
            lblHomeTeam.Text = dataRowHome["TeamName"].ToString();
            lblHomeTeam.Location = new Point(15, txtHomePred.Bottom + (i * 30));
            lblHomeTeam.AutoSize = true;

            txtHomePred.Text = "0";
            txtHomePred.Location = new Point(lblHomeTeam.Width, lblHomeTeam.Top - 3);
            txtHomePred.Width = 40;

            txtAwayPred.Text = "0";
            txtAwayPred.Location = new Point(txtHomePred.Width + lblHomeTeam.Width, txtHomePred.Top);
            txtAwayPred.Width = 40;

            lblAwayTeam.Text = dataRowAway["TeamName"].ToString();
            lblAwayTeam.Location = new Point(txtHomePred.Width + lblHomeTeam.Width + txtAwayPred.Width, txtHomePred.Top + 3);
            lblAwayTeam.AutoSize = true;

            pnlPredCard.Controls.Add(lblHomeTeam);
            pnlPredCard.Controls.Add(txtHomePred);
            pnlPredCard.Controls.Add(txtAwayPred);
            pnlPredCard.Controls.Add(lblAwayTeam);
```

So what my end goal is, is recieving the input from the user validating them and then storing them in a database.

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: Don't be so gender normative. :)

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: the problem is that I can't recieve the input the user will give in the textbox

Comment: Creating your own grid control with a bunch of textboxes is never not a mistake.  With the somewhat inevitable outcome that you don't know how to add a new row.  Use a DataGridView control if you want to get this project done.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment the labels and textboxes are placed in a datagridview the problem is that i can't get the input out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on how the user activates an event that requires the reading of the TextBox you have a few possible solutions.
Here is one where the TextBox (read all TextBox's) waits for enter:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while(someLoop)
    {
        TextBox theTextBox = new TextBox();
        theTextBox.Name = "SomeUniqeName";//Maybe team name?
        theTextBox.KeyUp += TheTextBox_KeyUp;
    }
}

private void TheTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
    {
        TextBox textbox = (TextBox) sender;//Get the textbox

        //Just an example
        listOfTeams.First( r => r.TeamName == textbox.Name )
                   .SomeOtherProperty = textbox.Text;
    }
}
```

The textbox's are now identifiable by their name and all have an event. No matter how many you make.

If you will store the data later with 1 click of a button (and another loop) this solution might be better:

```
string[] Teams = { "teamA", "teamB", "teamC" };
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < Teams.Length; i++ )
    {
        TextBox theTextBox = new TextBox();

        //Prefix the name so we know this is a betting textbox
        //Add the 'name' (teams[i] in this case) to find it
        theTextBox.Name = "ThePrefix" + Teams[i];
    }

}

private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //We want all betting textbox's here but also by team name
    for ( int i = 0; i < Teams.Length; i++ )
    {
        //Because we set the name, we can now find it with linq
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox) this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .FirstOrDefault( row => row.Name == "ThePrefix" + Teams[i] );
    }
}
```

This way each textbox is identifiable and won't conflict with other textbox's (because of 'ThePrefix'). This is essentially the other way around from the first method as it looks for the textbox based on data rather than data based on textbox name.

Comment: I have added some more code maybe that will make it more clear?

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt Maybe make your question more clear, I thought you wanted to be able to know which dynamically created textbox is which. I also can't do anything with the added code as I don't have the database. Try to make your question (problem) reproduce able

Comment: oke ill try for every "team" in the tabel team the loop makes a new label and a new textbox.  In every textbox the user can make a bet on what team will  score. When the player press a certain button all the input data from the textboxes will be put in a tabel.

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt Join my chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142494/windows-form-recieve-text-input

Comment: i dont have enough points for that im afraid maybe discord or something?

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt I gave you write access, that should work even if you don't have the rep

Comment: im afraid not :(

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt Darn it, so you want to store it in a table? Do you put a foreign key to the match or something in the bet?

Comment: nope, but that won't help now since i cant recieve the input??

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt How is it you can't receive input? And how do you link the bet to the correct teams in the db then?

Comment: well yeah thats the part of the problem i dont know :(

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt I posted another solution. If its still not what you want consider being more specific in your question (edit it)

Comment: I add a link to a pic where you can see the frame maybe that will make me more clear???

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt You added the picture, you want to do something on place bet I assume?

Comment: yes please, when that button is pressed all the input from the textboxes should be stored inside a tabel and later on the should be checked but thats not the main problem for now

Comment: @ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt my 2nd example shows you how you could get the data from each textbox so what's the problem if you store it using that....?

Comment: because dont they store 0 - 0 now for every match even before the player can give  a input??